# WPF - Hide a button within a template

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I've made a TabControl template. Within this template is a button.

If TabControl1 implements the template, the button should be visible.
If TabControl2 implements the template, the button should be hidden.

How would I do this? Is there a TabControl property that could be useful to bind to?

Comment: So the first `TabControl` created should have the `Button` visible, and every `TabControl` created after that should have the `Button` hidden?

Comment: It should be optional if the button should be visible or not.

Comment: Ok, can you please add the `TabControl` Template xaml code to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do would be to create a UserControl that inherits TabControl and add the dependencyProperty you want to bind to (e.g.: "ShowButton")

an other solution is to use the "Tag" property that has been added just for this reason: add you own custom property values to a control, but this is kind of a hack in this case a not very nice programming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions David. I think I'll go with the dependencyProperty solution.

Comment: you're welcome. Come back if you need help with the UserControl and the DP